# CoffeeScript recursive function

Tags: recursion, tree, coffeescript

I have a question about unexpected behaviour in a Coffeescript tree implementation, and wonder if anyone can help. I think the problem is to do with wrong "this" context, but I'm not sure where to put the fat arrow to resolve it. Perhaps someone who knows coffeescript better than I can explain the behaviour?

```
class Node
    uuid: undefined

    constructor: (@uuid) ->

class MultiNode extends Node
    branches: {}

    constructor: (args...) ->
        super(args...)

    print: (str = '') ->
        console.log "#{str}Multiway<#{@uuid}>"
        for value,node of @branches
            if node?
                node.print "#{str}  "

class LeafNode extends Node
    value: undefined

    constructor: (@value, args...) ->
        super(args...)

    print: (str = '') ->
        console.log "#{str}Leaf<#{@uuid}>: #{@value}"

tree = new MultiNode(1)
subtree1 = new MultiNode(2)
subtree1.branches["aa"] = new LeafNode("three",3)
subtree1.branches["ab"] = new LeafNode("four",4)
tree.branches["a"] = subtree1
subtree2 = new MultiNode(5)
subtree2.branches["ba"] = new LeafNode("six",6)
subtree2.branches["bb"] = new LeafNode("seven",7)
tree.branches["b"] = subtree2
tree.print()
```

This infinitely recurses, I think because the context of 'print' isn't set as I intend to
that of the subnode object. I'd appreciate any guidance.

D.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how you're defining `branches`:

```
class MultiNode extends Node
    branches: {}
```

That attaches `branches` to the `MultiNode` class so all `MultiNode` instances share exactly the same `@branches` through their prototype. This will make a big mess of things for obvious reasons. Anything you define at the class level is part of the prototype and none of that will get copied to instances unless you do it yourself.

All you need to do is make sure that each `MultiNode` instance gets its own `@branches`:

```
class MultiNode extends Node
    constructor: (args...) ->
        @branches = { }
        super(args...)
    #...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vkacZ/

Rule of thumb:

> Never define mutable values in the class/prototype in (Coffee|Java)Script, always define those per-instance in the constructor (unless of course you want to share...).

---

PS: You don't have to say:

```
if node?
    node.print "#{str}  "
```

You can just say this:

```
node?.print "#{str}  "
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. Perhaps I'm just being thick, but why do I get shared instances of '@branches' with my original definition when clearly I get different '@uuid' and '@value' instances? I thought that I would get shared instances if I defined it with "value=undefined" or "@value:undefined" in the class prototype?

Comment: You replace `@uuid` and `@value` with, essentially, `@value = something_else` and such. That gives you something that hides the prototype's version and you never notice the ones in the prototype. With `@branches`, you're modifying it directly with things like `@branches[x] = y` so you're modifying it without replacing/shadowing the reference.

Comment: Excellent, and thanks for your time. I'm more familiar with functional languages like Haskell, Erlang and F# and more traditional OO languages like C++, C#, Python, and the like and I guess it really shows. I hope your explanation helps others as well.